# What would be the equivalent of a datetime bigint column in roomdb

Tags: kotlin, android-room, android-room-prepackageddatabase

I have a pre-existing sqlite database, the date time is saved as ticks so the sqlite column is bigint. How would I create a roomdb entity for that?

I tried using Long in RoomDb but it shows as INTEGER when I generated a database, Also tried using a converter to Long to DateTime but it still store as integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried using Long in RoomDb but it shows as INTEGER when I generated a database, Also tried using a converter to Long to DateTime but it still store as integer.

That is correct Long (kotlin) would be stored in a column with an SQLite type of INTEGER, which can hold a 63 bit signed integer value.

Although in SQLite the column type is highly flexible (in most situations any type of value can be stored in any type of column) Room requires a much stricter column type limited to

- REAL (decimal type),
- INTEGER (an integer type which could be as low as Boolean or as large as to Long)
- TEXT (a stream of characters, such as String)
- BLOB (a stream of Bytes, such as ByteArray)

A TypeConverter is only required if a field in an `@Entity` annotated class is not catetered for directly (Room caters for the above) such as other objects (e.g. Date).

If you have a pre-existing database then it may well have to be converted to suit Room's expectattions.

You mention BIGINT as a type. Room will not accept this. The column type would have to be changed to INTEGER. The conversion of the column types (and importantly constraints such as NOT NULL) **MUST** match Room's expectations.

The simplest way to ascertain Room's expectations is to

1. define the `@Entity` annotated classes.
2. Include them in the `@Database`'s `entities` parameter.
3. Successfully compile the project (CTRL+F9)
4. Via the Android View find the java(generated) directory.
5. Within the directory find the file/class that is the same name as the `@Database` annotated class.
6. Within the class locate the createAllTables function, which contains the SQL Room would use to create the tables i.e. the tables **EXACTLY** as Room expects.

The database may, certainly in the case of using BIGINT as a column type, need to be converted. This could be prior to including the database file as an asset, or could be via the prepackageddatabase callback.